# USB wireless card, the driver is listed in debian wifi page and the installation page

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers

I have a usb wifi, [it's name and driver](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/LG_PW-DN427) are in wikidevi. On Ubuntu system, it is immediately recognized and connect well. In debian, no wireless network is shown. Is this because my corresponding driver not installed? How to fix?

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0b95:772b ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88772B
----> Bus 001 Device 006: ID 148f:3070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1017:1006 Speedy Industrial Supplies, Pte., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here is the output of:

```
lsmod | grep rt2800
rt2800usb              26222  0 
rt2x00usb              17642  1 rt2800usb
rt2800lib              81131  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              42331  3 rt2x00usb,rt2800lib,rt2800usb
mac80211              482315  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
crc_ccitt              12347  1 rt2800lib
usbcore               195468  6 asix,rt2x00usb,rt2800usb,usbhid,usbnet,xhci_hcd
```

output of `sudo iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

When I try to reinstall it, the message is that
[image]

#### edit

problem still not solved, I've tried to install the firmware from non-free, but still not work. The installer also do not recognize the .bin file. It seems that the corresponding firmware is in the right directory, here is some output:

```
/lib/firmware$ ls -al
total 60
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep  9 17:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root 4096 Sep  9 17:05 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 8192 Jun 16  2014 rt2561.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 8192 Jun 16  2014 rt2561s.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 8192 Jun 16  2014 rt2661.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 8192 Jun 16  2014 rt2860.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 8192 Jun 16  2014 rt2870.bin
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jun 16  2014 rt3070.bin -> rt2870.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4096 Jun 16  2014 rt3071.bin
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Jun 16  2014 rt3090.bin -> rt2860.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4096 Jun 16  2014 rt3290.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2048 Jun 16  2014 rt73.bin
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your link, the usb wifi is a *Ralink RT3070*.

Unfortunatly there is only a non-free driver available. (Which isn't preinstalled)

To install it you have to add the non-free repository and install the package `firmware-ralink`. ([more Details](https://wiki.debian.org/rt2800usb))

Comment: Thanks, but even after I installed it and reboot. Wireless still not working. any other ideas?

Comment: That's odd. Does `sudo ifconfig` list it?

Comment: Are there any wlan-errors mentioned in `sudo dmesg`?

Comment: no wlan listed by ifconifg, lsusb can show it.

Comment: dmesg says: `[    5.116173] usbcore: registered new interface driver rt2800usb  `

Comment: Blacklist `rt2800usb` then reboot

Comment: @GAD3R I did   `sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and add `blacklist rt2800usb` but no  vain.

Comment: @GAD3R To be safe, I also add this line into the list of fbdev-blacklist.conf

Answer (score 0):

Download the `firmware-ralink_0.43_all.deb` from [here](http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/firmware-nonfree/)

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/firmware-nonfree/firmware-ralink_0.43_all.deb
```

Extract it :

```
ar vx firmware-ralink_0.43_all.deb
```

You will get 3 files:

```
x - debian-binary
x - control.tar.gz
x - data.tar.xz
```

Uncompress the `data.tar.xz` file :

```
tar xf data.tar.xz
```

`cd` to `/lib/firmware` and list the binary:

```
rt2561.bin  rt2561s.bin  rt2661.bin  rt2860.bin  rt2870.bin  rt3070.bin  rt3071.bin  rt3090.bin  rt3290.bin  rt73.bin
```

Copy the `rt2870.bin` to your USB then connect it , the installer will detect and install the firmware, to get the wifi working.

Comment: how to copy it to my usb?

Comment: right click copy and past .

Comment: but the usb wifi doesn't show itself...

Comment: you mean copy it to my usb installer and reinstall the system?

Comment: Copy and past the firmware to your USB data storage

Comment: No another USB , it dosn't work if you will use the Bootable USB you need a 2d USB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45142/discussion-between-gad3r-and-buzhidao).